# Correct value for `startCursor` and `endCursor` in `PageInfo` when there are 0 items/edges? Is the Relay pagination spec incorrect?

Tags: graphql, pagination, relay

[The Relay pagination specification](https://relay.dev/graphql/connections.htm#sec-undefined.PageInfo) says the following about `PageInfo`:

> It must also contain fields `startCursor` and `endCursor`, both of which return non-null opaque strings.
>
> [...]
>
> `startCursor` and `endCursor` must be the cursors corresponding to the first and last nodes in edges, respectively.

But what if I want to return zero items? There are lots of reason why a request to that specific endpoint would return an empty connection.

I don't see what values `startCursor` and `endCursor` should have in that case. The obvious answer is `null`, but the spec explicitly says "non-null". What's up with that?

For what it's worth, I looked at roughly 15 articles about the topic of "graphql pagination" and all of those either ignore the issue or assign `null` in the case of an empty list. So at this point it seems that the spec is just wrong or incompatible with the real world?

Comment: did you find out anything yet (I'm running into the same issue)

Comment: @pvgoddijn Nope, unfortunately not. In my project, I proceeded by making them nullable, but I'm still hoping for a proper answer to this.

Comment: i'm currently going for returning the 'from' cursor from the request (since that is where they are coming from so I sort of makes some sense but still feels ugly). But this is a gap in the spec IMHO,

Comment: @pvgoddijn But the `from` cursor is usually an optional parameter, right? So what do you do if it is not specified and you still want to return 0 items, because e.g. the database is empty?

Comment: i didnt think about that edge case yet...

Comment: filed a bug with the relay github: https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/3708 returning null seems tp be connonical

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: (31-01-2022): The spec was updated and these fields are now officially nullable.

([with this pull request](https://github.com/facebook/relay/pull/2655) )

---

I Filed a bug on the relay Github: https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/3708

It seems the canonical solution is to ignore the spec and make them non-null as both the JavaScript and java implementations do that.

Graphql-Relay-JS:
https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/blob/3796e0904fbfe0dd86e540d5b4df236330c8a5e7/src/connection/arrayConnection.ts

Java:
https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/1ee9630c7d25ccb55a5b1d9b1ccf7bf7895a8c7f/src/main/java/graphql/relay/Relay.java#L54